# PHP script query de MS Sql para My Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query, sql-insert

Boa tarde.
Como poderei fazer uma consulta em MS Sql e inserir os valores numa tabela de My Sql através do PHP?

Olhando para estes dados, tem como fazer essa inserção?

```
    #--> conexao mysql
    require_once("mysql.php");
    #--> conexao mssql
    require_once("mssql.php");
    #--> consulta sql server
    $sqlserver= "select * from sql_server_table";
    $sqlserverResult = odbc_exec($conMsSql, $sqlserver);
    #--> insere no MySql
    mysql_query("insert into mysql_table (col1, col2, col3) values ($sqlserverResult)";
```

Comment: Sim é possível dessa forma. Ai você escolhe se faz o insert no mysql para cada linha do mssql em um while, ou gera um consulta de um insert com multiplos `values()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer um insert no mysql para cada linha do mssql dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM mssql_table";

$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
        $insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO mysql_table(c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                            $row['c1'], $row['c2'], $row['c3'], $row['c4']);

        if(!mysql_query($insert)){
            echo 'linha com id: '. $row['c1'] , ' não foi inserida';
        }
    }
}
```

Ou pode fazer a consulta no SQL Server e gerar um string com um insert a multiplos `VALUES`, dessa forma todos os registros serão inseridos ou nenhum deles.

```
$sql = "SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM mssql_table";

$insert = "INSERT INTO mysql_table(c1, c2, c3, c4) VALUES ";

$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
    $insert .= sprintf(" ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),", $row['c1'], $row['c2'], $row['c3'], $row['c3']);     
}

$insert = trim($insert, ','); //remove a ultima virgula

if(!mysql_query($insert)){
    echo 'nenhum registro foi inserido. Erro: '. mysql_error();
}
```