# Inserir múltiplos registros no MySql com base em um valor X e adicionar valores fixos

Tags: php, mysqli

Preciso inserir múltiplos registros no banco de dados, mas sem vir de um formulário. Por exemplo:

Tenho um valor 50 (seria o número de registros que preciso inserir) e um id de amarração que precisa ser igual para todos os registros.

A minha pergunta é: *como faço para inserir sem precisar vir de um formulário esses valores?*

Já tentei com os exemplos aqui do fórum, mas todos eles usam valores passados por formulários.

No meu caso não tenho formulário tenho somente a quantidade de registros que preciso inserir.

Comment: É so definir os valores pode jogar dentro de um for ou montar um inset unico.

Comment: Eu já tentei, mas não consegui.

Comment: @rray consegue me dar uma luz ?

Comment: Tem alguns exemplos de como montar o insert ou de pegar o id inserido. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89841/91 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94216/91

Comment: Nos exemplos não tem a lógica que preciso. 
Como no exemplo que dei:
Preciso inserir 50 novos registros, ID Primary é AUTO, O nome teria que ser NOME 1, NOME  2, NOME 3 assim por diante e ID de amarração com outras tabelas seria um fixo por exemplo 2.
1, NOME 1, 2
1, NOME 2, 2

Comment: @rray Entendeu como seria ?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma solução!
Não sei se é a solução mais correta para o que eu queria, mas foi a que encontrei.

Vou deixar aqui para quem estiver procurando algo parecido:

```
//Aqui eu defino a quantidade de registros que eu quero inserir. No caso aqui são 109 registros.
$valores = range(1, 109);

//Aqui posso definir o valor que eu preciso que seja igual em todos os registros adicionados
$id_empresa = '2';
$nome_pesquisa = 'Pesquisa Setor A';

for ($i = 0, $total = count($valores); $i < $total; $i++) {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO pesquisa(id_empresa, nome) VALUES('$id_empresa','$nome_pesquisa')");
}
```